# Following a video and when using the array my fans are in all diferent Z positions

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm sorry i'm very new to blender but I'm trying to make a CPU cooler and in the video his array goes nicely around the cylinder but for me the fans go in a different position and i'm not sure how to fix this

[image: Fans not following the cylinder]

Comment: Hello, you must make sure that the empty that you are using as array Object is set at the exact same point as the fan origin, alos apply its scale

Comment: If moonroots comment doesn’t help, pls provide blend file. We can help

Comment: @moonboots: is "alos" french and means something like "allons-y"? :D

Comment: you shouldn't say sorry, that you are a beginner. we all started one day. But it is an important information, so i would always add it to the question so that the one who answer know how detailed the answer should be ;)

Comment: @Chris, you say "If moonroots comment doesn’t help", how dare you?!??

Comment: and "alos" is a very mean insult in french that i can't translate

Comment: @moonboots: i can dare because i am not afraid of being killed by superman. It's a quick pain free death...so that's ok ;)

Comment: i knew you aren't as nice as you pretend to be....!!!!!! :D :D

Comment: @moonboots that did it ! the fans are now in the correct place, thank you

Comment: @Chris Thank you for offering help as well appreciate it :)

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: by the way, mooonboots, what happened?! are u chilling? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4yEf.png

Comment: @Chris I can't hurt you, you have kryptonite. About my score, you need to know that I'm the one who gave you most of your reputation points (I gave you 4000 this january, don't know the one who gave you 39)

Comment: @moonboots: thank you sooooo much. You are too generous to me!!!! I wondered myself where i got those points from too....i tried to downvote you as much as i can...but as soon as i tried to click it...i got hit by a flash and couldn't move for hours....!!! 

Comment: so you're the one who downvote me...   :/  i'm so disapointed... btw, I've subscribed 620 times to your youtube chanel, I guess the 621th is yourself, now I think I'm going to unsubscribe...

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the empty that you are using as array *Object* is set at the exact same point as the fan origin, also apply the object scale.

Comment: i pressed downvote....and woooahaaa..you got +1 again! how do you do this!?

Comment: it's a little python script that only gandalf and i know

Comment: i suspect it's the way he got 150 000 points by the way

Comment: gandalf is....your father? :S

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL

Comment: i don't know, he's a guy who thinks he's smart

Comment: he has 151K.... ;) (oh man, Marty and Gordon's behaviour is coming over me....) :(

Comment: yes, 151k with very lazy answers

Comment: he is gandalf3 - maybe just continuing his fathers and grandfathers account.... ;) so gandalf2 and gandalf1